# "Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (OleStr)" when using numbers in SQL query

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I am trying to check if a specific username exists within a database (Access) using SQL. If I use only letter or string characters the code works fine but when I use numbers as in the example below even though I insert them as a string I get the error:

> "Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (OleStr)"

```
  DataModule.Query.Active := False;
  sQuery := 'SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username = "31"';
  DataModule.Query.SQL.Text := sQuery;
  DataModule.Query.Active := True;
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

edit:

The debugger gives the error just after the if line in the following code

```
 if UpperCase(DataModule.Query['Username']) = sUsername then
  begin
    if DataModule.Query['Password'] = sPassword then
    begin
      bPass := True;
    end
```

[Solved]

Thank you all for the advice I got it working!

Comment: Use a parametrized query! That's what they are made for. As an alternative use single quotes.

Comment: What Uwe Raabe says.  But please show in your code *exactly* where the error occurs.

Comment: I changed my main post to show where the error takes place

Comment: Make sure you are checking for BOF/EOF before reading any values, and also check for NULL values before comparing values. But why are you comparing the username manually when the query already did that for you? And why not put the password in the query as well? You should also consider using `COUNT()` instead of `*` unless you are planning on reading other values from the found record. It is wasteful to query values you are not going to use.

Comment: I Don't know which component type is `Query` but you might want to try: `Query.FieldByName('Username').AsString`. This will eliminate NULL issue. It is also a good idea to check for `Query.IsEmpty` before you actually test the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm still in the learning phase. I appreciate the helpful advice.

Comment: Query is a TADOquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Query.FieldByName('Password').AsString` (same for Username field) to eliminate any NULL issues. `.AsString` will convert db NULLs to Delphi empty string `''`.

After you open your query you need to test if there are any records before you actually test username/password logic.

Note: You don't need to check the Username again because if the query returned results there is a match and that user exists in your table:

```
bPass := False;
if not DataModule.Query.IsEmpty then
  if DataModule.Query.FieldByName('Password').AsString = sPassword then
    begin
      bPass := True;
    end
```

As already mentioned you better use parameterized query. or at least use [`QuotedStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.QuotedStr) to avoid SQL injection. e.g.:

```
sQuery := 'SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username = ' + QuotedStr('31');
```

A parameterized query should look like this:

```
sQuery := 'SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username = :Username';
DataModule.Query.SQL.Text := sQuery;
DataModule.Query.ParamByName('Username').Value := '31';
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserName = :UserName AND Password = :Password` with subsequent checking dataset record count is also an option here.

Comment: @TLama: Not record count. Bad! :-) Use `IsEmpty`, which doesn't require retrieval of all data and therefore is much quicker (and a much better habit to develop).

Comment: @TLama, You are correct about option of checking both `UserName` *AND* `Password`, and then checking if the record set is not empty. *but* it depends on the prompt you need to show to the end user. e.g. You might want to tell him the `UserName` does not exists. and later tell him the password is not correct. If you check both `UserName AND Password` in a single query you can't know *why* user failed to login in case of empty record set. Personally I would use a SP and return a status back, but this is out of this scope.

Comment: Also the OP's method could be useful in case you store the password Encrypted in the db, and the Decryption logic is in the client. but usually you will store a password hash only (e.g. MD5)